# Apache .htaccess - how to rewrite referrer?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a site www.example.com.

I would like to achieve the following:
All the visits that click on `www.example.com` from my other site `www.example.net`, to have the referrer `www.example.org`.

In other words. I want to rewrite the referrer www.example.net with www.example.org. In a way that in the server logs of `www.example.com` it will look like that the traffic is coming from `www.example.org` instead than `www.example.net`.

If somebody click to `www.example.com` from a page, for example `www.example.net/whatever/`, in the logs I would like to see `www.example.org`. So I do not want to see the pages as referrer. Just the homepage of `www.example.org` is enough.

How to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sure can be achieved with something like

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com myreferer
CustomLog access.log combined env=!myreferer
CustomLog access.log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"http://www.example.com/\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" env=myreferer
```

The first line sets environment variable myreferer if the user is coming from example.com. When set, the third line specifies modified log format, otherwise standard "combined" log format is used.

I'd still not recommend this since it will cause losing information. If you try to achieve this because you need these referers to show as one on some kind of log analysis tool, you should have settings for that in the tool itself.

Comment: Thanks, and where is www.mysite.com defined?

Comment: In WHOIS database, saying it is property of United Online Web Services, Inc. Therefore, you should use permissible domains like example.com. It is not really that hard to find out which line does what, especially when it's explained on the next paragraph.